# How to cache static images on react project

Tags: reactjs, http-headers, browser-cache

I'm working on a react project(web), which has many static images on pages. The problem is that images are rarely change, but every request for images check the image has changed and get 304 status code. Each request takes about less than 1sec, but due to many images, it's annoying and not good for user experience. How can I cache images to prevent not sending request for specific images? If there are several solutions, which would be a good solution?

Comment: What is a "request for images"? Is it an API call that gets multiple images and you're calling it repeatedly?

Comment: It means img tag. <img src /> tags are making the requests.

Comment: Why are your `<img/>` making multi requests while you're on a page? Are you using `this.setState` to control your `src`?

Comment: I mean `img` tags are on every page (every component). Each time components render, requests for `img` tags occur.